# Navigate back from UITabviewController to ViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My hierarchy

```
 UINavigationController -> UIViewController 
 -> UITabViewController 
     -> ViewController1                                                      
     -> ViewController2
     -> ViewController3
```

I want to navigate back from

```
ViewController1 -> UIViewController.
```

Anyone know please solve this issues.

Answer (score 1):

**"Unwind" is your answer.**

[image]

Create an `IBAction` method to unwind segue. Define this method in a controller in which you want to unwind (Controller from you want to jump back to main controller).

```
- (IBAction) prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
```

Now connect back button (in this case "Home" button) with this method in Storyboard. To connect unwind action -> Ctrl-drag to "Exit" outlet button of your controller.

[image]

**Note:** If you are using Xcode version less than 6.0 than "Exit" outlet is located at bottom of your view controller.

[image]

This will navigate back to your root navigation controller. That is UIViewController.

For further separation you can give an identifier to unwind segue and make different actions for exit to last controller.

Select identifier from left list and give an identifier in Attributes inspector.

[image]
[image]

**Key points:**

1. Write unwind method in a controller which will be exited.
2. Connection to "Exit" delegate will only works after you define unwind method.
3. Ctrl+Drag from a control to the Exit symbol to select the unwind segue you want this control to perform
4. Unwind segues appear below the Exit symbol for each connection made
5. You can give those unwind segues an identifier to have different activities performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    [navigationController popToViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

just provide the instance of the viewController you want to pop to and set animated property to YES if u want pop with animation and NO if not.

Comment: Since your UIViewController is the rootViewController of the navigation controller try using  [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:<#(BOOL)#>];

Comment: check if the navigation controller or the UIViewController is nil. If it is nil it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here the controller `UIViewController` is the rootViewController of `UINavigationController`. So you just need to pop to the `rootViewController` from the `ViewController1`

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done by this:

```
ViewController *loginVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self.navigationController popToViewController: loginVC animated:YES]
```